# Why does rake jasmine pass but rake jasmine:ci fails with TypeError: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, rake

With rake jasmine all my tests pass in the browser.

With rake jasmine, 2 specs fail with:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'expect(player).not.toBePlaying(song)') in http://localhost:36091/__spec__/PlayerSpec.js (line 28)
```

I've configured my `spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml` file so that it has

```
src_files:
  - src/Player.js
  - src/Song.js
spec_files:
  - '**/*[sS]pec.js'
src_dir:
spec_dir: spec
```

`src/Song.js` has:

```
function Song() {
...
```

Why is `rake jasmine:ci` failing for those two examples?

The code for the first failing one is:

```
it("should be able to play a Song", function() {
  player.play(song);
  expect(player.currentlyPlayingSong).toEqual(song);

  //demonstrates use of custom matcher
  expect(player).toBePlaying(song);  # <-- error here
});
```

`Song.js` does seem to be loaded because if I remove it all 5 examples fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed the custom matcher `toBePlaying`

I was able to get all the specs passing by changing this in the `spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml` file:

```
src_files:
  - src/Player.js
  - src/Song.js
  - spec/SpecHelper.js   # <--- Added to include the custom helper 'toBePlaying'
```

I had tried adding it to the `spec_files` section but it needs to be listed in `src_files`